# how to make cassandra in Azure talk to nodejs app using datastax driver?

Tags: node.js, azure, cassandra, datastax, bitnami

I have a `Cassandra certified by bitnami` VM instance running on Azure.

How to make it talk to my nodejs app by using datastax nodejs driver?

More specifically,

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ /* What goes in here? */ });
```

Suppose this is my VM details:

```
IP Address: a.b.c.d
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're stuck on. Each node in your Cassandra cluster should have an inbound port open, right? Then you just point to your cluster node as you'd normally do, whether via external ip address or via internal address (assuming your code is in the same vnet as your cluster).

Comment: `const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: [ ip ] }) `

Comment: @jorgebg if I do that I get the following error:
{ [Error: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, IP:9042: Error: Connection timeout. See innerErrors.]
  innerErrors:
   { 'IP:9042':
      { [Error: Connection timeout]
        message: 'Connection timeout',
        info: 'Cassandra Driver Error' } },
  info: 'Represents an error when a query cannot be performed because no host is available or could be reached by the driver.',
  message: 'All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, IP:9042: Error: Connection timeout. See innerErrors.' }